# Cant get Minecraft armor textures to work

Tags: java, textures, minecraft

I am very new to coding and all i am trying to do is make a minecraft mod. I am trying to add armors but I cant get the textures to work. here is my code and error in console:

```
package com.halo.halomod.armor;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IIconRegister;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemArmor;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;

import com.halo.halomod.halo;

public class TitaniumArmor extends ItemArmor {
    private String [] armourTypes = new Strenter code here`ing [] {"TitaniumHelmet", "TitaniumChestplate", "TitaniumLeggings", "TitaniumBoots"};


    public TitaniumArmor(ArmorMaterial armorMaterial, int renderIndex, int armourType) {
        super(armorMaterial, renderIndex, armourType);
    }

    @Override
    public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int slot, String layar){
        if(stack.getItem().equals(halo.TitaniumHelmet)|| stack.getItem().equals(halo.TitaniumChestplate)|| stack.getItem().equals(halo.TitaniumBoots)){
            return "halo:textures/armor/titanium1.png";
        }

        if(stack.getItem().equals(halo.TitaniumLeggings)){
            return "halo:textures/armor/titanium2.png"; 
        }
        else return null;
    }
    public void registerIconsRegister(IIconRegister reg){ 
        if(this == halo.TitaniumHelmet)
            this.itemIcon = reg.registerIcon("halo:Titanium Helmet");
        if(this == halo.TitaniumChestplate)
            this.itemIcon = reg.registerIcon("halo:Titanium Chestplate");
        if(this == halo.TitaniumLeggings)
            this.itemIcon = reg.registerIcon("halo:Titanium Leggings");
        if(this == halo.TitaniumBoots)
            this.itemIcon = reg.registerIcon("halo:Titanium Boots");
    }
}
```

Error in Console:

> [15:53:29] [Client thread/ERROR]: Using missing texture, unable to
>   load
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4103_TitaniumHelmet.png
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4103_TitaniumHelmet.png    at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:65)
>   ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:67)
>   ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTextureAtlas(TextureMap.java:128)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTexture(TextureMap.java:93)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTexture(TextureManager.java:89)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTickableTexture(TextureManager.java:71)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTextureMap(TextureManager.java:58)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:621)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:931)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:112) [Main.class:?]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?] [15:53:29] [Client thread/ERROR]: Using
>   missing texture, unable to load
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4106_TitaniumBoots.png
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4106_TitaniumBoots.png     at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:65)
>   ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:67)
>   ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTextureAtlas(TextureMap.java:128)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTexture(TextureMap.java:93)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTexture(TextureManager.java:89)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTickableTexture(TextureManager.java:71)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTextureMap(TextureManager.java:58)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:621)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:931)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:112) [Main.class:?]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?] [15:53:29] [Client thread/ERROR]: Using
>   missing texture, unable to load
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4104_TitaniumChestplate.png
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4104_TitaniumChestplate.png
>     at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:65)
>   ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:67)
>   ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTextureAtlas(TextureMap.java:128)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTexture(TextureMap.java:93)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTexture(TextureManager.java:89)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTickableTexture(TextureManager.java:71)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTextureMap(TextureManager.java:58)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:621)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:931)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:112) [Main.class:?]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?] [15:53:29] [Client thread/ERROR]: Using
>   missing texture, unable to load
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4105_TitaniumLeggings.png
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   minecraft:textures/items/MISSING_ICON_ITEM_4105_TitaniumLeggings.png
>     at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.FallbackResourceManager.getResource(FallbackResourceManager.java:65)
>   ~[FallbackResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.getResource(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:67)
>   ~[SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]    at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTextureAtlas(TextureMap.java:128)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.loadTexture(TextureMap.java:93)
>   [TextureMap.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTexture(TextureManager.java:89)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTickableTexture(TextureManager.java:71)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.loadTextureMap(TextureManager.java:58)
>   [TextureManager.class:?]  at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:621)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:931)
>   [Minecraft.class:?]   at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:112) [Main.class:?]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_09]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]     at
>   net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
>   [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?] [15:53:29] [Client thread/INFO]: Created:
>   256x256 textures/items-

Comment: You haven't asked a question - you've *just* given us your code, with no indication of what you're trying to achieve, or what's going wrong, beyond "trying to add armors" and "cant get the textures to work". That really doesn't give us much information at all. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I am new to coding so I don't really know what my question is

Comment: but I just want to know why the textures are not working and how to get them to work

Comment: If you can't even describe what's wrong (i.e. what happens compared with what you want to happen) it's unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: "Are not working" doesn't describe what's wrong.

Comment: I am trying to add textures to my mod but I keep getting the missing texture thing. idk what more to describe

Comment: "The missing texture thing"? What "missing texture thing"? Bear in mind that people trying to help you may not have played Minecraft or written any Minecraft mods. How would you explain what you're seeing to someone with *no experience* of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Edit it into the question. I don't have any more time to help now, but the more information you can give, the more likely it is that someone else can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are in your `public void registerIconsRegister(IIconRegister reg)` method:

Firstly, the method you're supposed to be overriding is defined as:

```
public void registerIcons(net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IconRegister register)
```

So that method isn't being called, and even if it were, all of your equal checks will fail:

```
if(this == halo.TitaniumHelmet)
```

As neither `ItemArmor` nor `Item` override `Object.equals(Object obj)`, Java will perform memory reference checks which will all fail. Regardless, the `registerIcons` method should register all item icons, regardless of what metadata based sub-Items exist, so just remove the `if` statements entirely.

Comment: i don't understand what you are saying how can i fix it and get it to work?

Comment: are you saying to add @Override to the registerIconsRegister(IIconRegister reg)?

Comment: @user3478462 No I'm saying there is no method called `registerIconsRegister(IIconRegister reg)`. Look at the source code for `ItemArmor` and `Item`.

Comment: i am just following a tutorial but what do i do to fix it and get it to work?

Comment: i did that but it stll is not working and i can seem to post the code